# Send mail category data to Excel using Outlook VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I count the number of emails in Outlook by Category.

I am getting the output in a MsgBox.

[image]

I want the output in Excel.

Example-

Category                  No of Emails
Material(blue)            42
Vendor(green)              5

Macro used as below

```
Sub CategoriesEmails()

Dim oFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim oDict As Object
Dim sStartDate As String
Dim sEndDate As String
Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
Dim sStr As String
Dim sMsg As String

On Error Resume Next
Set oFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

sStartDate = Date - 365
sEndDate = Date
Set oItems = oFolder.Items.Restrict("[Received] >= '" & sStartDate & "' And [Received] <= '" & sEndDate & "'")
oItems.SetColumns ("Categories")

For Each aitem In oItems
    sStr = aitem.Categories
    If Not oDict.Exists(sStr) Then
        oDict(sStr) = 0
    End If
    oDict(sStr) = CLng(oDict(sStr)) + 1
Next aitem

sMsg = ""
For Each aKey In oDict.Keys
    sMsg = sMsg & aKey & ":   " & oDict(aKey) & vbCrLf
Next
MsgBox sMsg

Set oFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Outlook by default (newer versions) can't run VBA, you will need to change a regex value to get that running. But your question is a bit vague/unclear.

Comment: I have added the code in the question which i used to run to get the output as msgbox, i want the same results in excel instead of msgbox. Please help with that.

I hope its clear now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, I've updated my code, you can paste all and run it:

```
 Sub CategoriesEmails()

    Dim oFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim sStartDate As String
    Dim sEndDate As String
    Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim sStr As String
    Dim sMsg As String
    Dim strFldr As String
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim xlApp As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    sStartDate = Date - 365
    sEndDate = Date
    Set oItems = oFolder.Items.Restrict("[Received] >= '" & sStartDate & "' And [Received] <= '" & sEndDate & "'")
    oItems.SetColumns ("Categories")

    For Each aItem In oItems
    sStr = aItem.Categories
    If Not oDict.Exists(sStr) Then
    oDict(sStr) = 0
    End If
    oDict(sStr) = CLng(oDict(sStr)) + 1
    Next aItem

    sMsg = ""
    i = 0

    strFldr = "D:\"
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Application.Visible = True
    xlApp.Workbooks.Open strFldr & "test.xlsx"
    xlApp.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    For Each aKey In oDict.Keys
    xlApp.Range("a1").Offset(i, 0).Value = sMsg & aKey
    xlApp.Range("B1").Offset(i, 0).Value = oDict(aKey) & vbCrLf
    i = i + 1
    Next
    xlApp.Save

    Set oFolder = Nothing

     End Sub
```

You could change the fileUrl, fileName, Excel field as your actual situation.

Comment: Hi thanks for providing the solution but i am looking for the count only for the no of mails in each categories along with the Category name..

I have macro for displaying the count as Msgbox ,, i want that in Excel.

Above is the code and the Screenshot..

Comment: Hi,
your code run perfectly fine.. I just need one more help that along with the category count, can i also get the category's oldest email date?

Comment: @AbhishekSinghal Ask a separate on-topic question.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` masks two non-fatal errors in this answer. `oItems.SetColumns ("Categories")` and `xlApp.Save`.