# How to count and export the number, and names of categories in outlook to excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have code that allows you to enter a date range, to get the information I want. My problem is in the next step of exporting that data to excel.

I have tried VBA to run from excel, and couldn't get the results I want. Unfortunately I am not familiar with VBA in outlook

```
Sub CategoriesEmails()

Dim oFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim oDict As Object
Dim sStartDate As String
Dim sEndDate As String
Dim oItems As Outlook.items
Dim sStr As String
Dim sMsg As String


On Error Resume Next
Set oFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

sStartDate = InputBox("Type the start date (format MM/DD/YYYY)")
sEndDate = InputBox("Type the end date (format MM/DD/YYYY)")

Set oItems = oFolder.items.Restrict("[Received] >= '" & sStartDate & "' And [Received] <= '" & sEndDate & "'")
oItems.SetColumns ("Categories")

For Each aitem In oItems
sStr = aitem.Categories
If Not oDict.exists(sStr) Then
oDict(sStr) = 0
End If
oDict(sStr) = CLng(oDict(sStr)) + 1
Next aitem

sMsg = ""
For Each aKey In oDict.keys
sMsg = sMsg & aKey & ":   " & oDict(aKey) & vbCrLf
Next
MsgBox sMsg

Set oFolder = Nothing

 End Sub
```

I expect the information to be shown in a message box, which this code accomplishes.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code to see how your Dictionary is being populated?

Comment: Are you saying that you are able to see the data in msgbox and just want that data to be imported to excel sheet? or you cannot see the data in msgbox?

Comment: @Zac, yes I can see the data! The code works as intended! I would just like to export the data into excel rather than have it display in a msgbox. Thank you and Eric for the quick replies

Comment: The `FOR` loop that adds your `oDict` items to `sMsg`.. rather than adding to `sMsg`, just write it straight to your sheet (i.e. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iRow).Value = aKey & ":   " & oDict(aKey)`. `iRow` would be a **Long** datatype). Or you could add it to an array and transpose it to your range

Comment: Awesome! This helps! I think I added everything in correctly but I still can't get it to copy and paste where I want. Do you have any more advice?

Comment: **where I want**: where in the sheet are you trying to copy it? Also, when you reply, don't forget to add **@<username>** otherwise we don't get a notification

Comment: @Zac, thank you for all the help! This is my first post so I don't know all the ins and out quite yet! I added in code to created a new workbook and I would like to paste it in the new workbook created. I have it to where it creates it, but doesn't paste in the data. I am just happy to have it paste anywhere!

Comment: Create a new worksheet variable and set it to your new sheet (I'm presuming that your new sheet is in the same workbook? If so, do something like: `Dim oWS as Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("New Worksheet")`. Change **New Worksheet** to whatever your new worksheet is called). Now you can just: `oWS.Range("A" & iRow).Value = aKey & ": " & oDict(aKey)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send mail category data to Excel using Outlook VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53476842/send-mail-category-data-to-excel-using-outlook-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Although dates and times are typically stored with a `Date` format, the `Find` and `Restrict` methods require that the date and time be converted to a string representation. To make sure that the date is formatted as Microsoft Outlook expects, use the `Format` function.

For example, you may find similar posts there - [Outlook Items Restrict with Date issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38310690/outlook-items-restrict-with-date-issue).