# Can I add "export to excel" to an existing VBA for Outlook?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, export-to-excel, com-automation

I have been using the code below to calculate the total hours spent between 2 dates by category.  It works perfectly, and now I'm looking for a way to not only run this code but also export the data collected to a specific excel worksheet.  Is there a simple addition to the code below, or do I have to have a completely different sub?

```
Sub TotalCategories()

Dim app As New Outlook.Application
Dim namespace As Outlook.namespace
Dim calendar As Outlook.Folder
Dim appt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim apptList As Outlook.Items
Dim apptListFiltered As Outlook.Items
Dim explorer As Outlook.explorer
Dim view As Outlook.view
Dim calView As Outlook.CalendarView
Dim startDate As String
Dim endDate As String
Dim category As String
Dim duration As Integer
Dim outMsg As String

' Access appointment list
Set namespace = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set calendar = namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
Set apptList = calendar.Items

' Include recurring appointments and sort the list
apptList.IncludeRecurrences = True
apptList.Sort "[Start]"

' Get selected date
Set explorer = app.ActiveExplorer()
Dim dte As String
 startDate = InputBox("Please Enter Start Date: ", Default:=Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy"))
 endDate = InputBox("Please Enter End Date: ", Default:=Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy"))

' Filter the appointment list
strFilter = "[Start] >= '" & startDate & "'" & " AND [End] <= '" & endDate & "'"
Set apptListFiltered = apptList.Restrict(strFilter)

' Loop through the appointments and total for each category
Set catHours = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each appt In apptListFiltered
    category = appt.Categories
    duration = appt.duration
    If catHours.Exists(category) Then
        catHours(category) = catHours(category) + duration
    Else
        catHours.Add category, duration
    End If
Next

' Loop through the categories
keyArray = catHours.Keys
For Each Key In keyArray
    outMsg = outMsg & Key & ": " & (catHours(Key) / 60) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
Next

' Display final message
MsgBox outMsg, , "Category Totals"

' Clean up objects
Set app = Nothing
Set namespace = Nothing
Set calendar = Nothing
Set appt = Nothing
Set apptList = Nothing
Set apptListFiltered = Nothing
Set explorer = Nothing
Set view = Nothing
Set calView = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send mail category data to Excel using Outlook VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53476842/send-mail-category-data-to-excel-using-outlook-vba)

Answer (score 0):

You can automate Excel in place where you can write the collected data instantly to the worksheet. The Excel object model is described in depth in the [Excel VBA reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel) section of MSDN. You just need to add an Excel COM reference. See [Controlling One Microsoft Office Application from Another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/working-with-other-applications/controlling-one-microsoft-office-application-from-another) for more information.

Comment: I'm sorry... I'm VERY new to using VBA.

Comment: See [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office).

Comment: I've worked on this for days... I still have no idea how to export the collected report data to Excel.